# Add second category BOX for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

My problem is that I want to add another group of categories. I have my main Categories where I have some items but I need another Cateogry BOX for another items. Please see the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/259qJ.jpg

Is there any plugin that can do that? Or what can you suggest me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is a custom taxonomy, there are many plugins available to create that for you like ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ ).

In wordpress the 'Categories' is one type of taxonomy.

More about taxonomy : http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies